# Can the acme-account-creation-tool be used as a module in my go project?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-secrets-manager

Instructions to run the tool involve downloading the repo. However, I would like to use it within my go project. I tried importing it according to the path github.ibm.com/acme-account in the go.mod file, however it does not match the path of the repo github.com/ibm-cloud-security/acme-account-creation-tool@none Could the go.mod be possibly updated?

Comment: Are you referring to this? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/secrets-manager?topic=secrets-manager-add-certificate-authority&interface=ui#add-certificate-authority-supported

Comment: I'm referring to the acme account creation process here, [https://github.com/ibm-cloud-security/acme-account-creation-tool](https://github.com/ibm-cloud-security/acme-account-creation-tool). I was hoping to do this within my go program, as opposed to manually downloading the repo

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this up.
The go.mod has been updated.

Thank you